# Template or function arguments as implementation details in doxygen?

Tags: c++, parameters, doxygen

In doxygen is there any common way to specify that some C++ template parameters of function parameters are implementation details and should not be specified by the user ?

For example, a template parameter used as recursion level counter in metaprogramming technique or a SFINAE parameter in a function ?

For example :

```
/// \brief Do something
/// \tparam MyFlag A flag...
/// \tparam Limit Recursion limit
/// \tparam Current Recursion level counter. SHOULD NOT BE EXPLICITELY SPECIFIED !!!
template<bool MyFlag, unsigned int Limit, unsigned int Current = 0> myFunction();
```

Is there any doxygen normalized option equivalent to "SHOULD NOT BE EXPLICITELY SPECIFIED !!!" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that the whole template is an implementation detail of a different interface:

```
template<bool MyFlag, unsigned int Limit, unsigned int Current = 0> myFunctionImpl();

template<bool MyFlag, unsigned int Limit> myFunction() {
   myFunctionImpl<MyFlag, Limit, 0>();
}
```

Now it becomes easier to document: `myFunction()` (and all it's arguments) are part of the interface, which does not include the iteration counter. `myFunctionImpl()` is the implementation of that interface and does not need to be documented at all (or only minimally with a comment stating that it is an implementation detail and user code should not depend on it or use it directly). If you want, you can enclose the implementation in an `#ifdef` block so that the doxygen preprocessor removes it and it does not appear in the generated documentation.

Answer (score 0):

One option to convey that a parameter should not be specified would be to hide it in the documentation. For example you could conditionally compile out the internal parameters:

```
/// \brief Do something
/// \tparam MyFlag A flag...
/// \tparam Limit Recursion limit
template<bool MyFlag, unsigned int Limit
#if !defined(DOXYGEN)
        , unsigned int Current = 0
#endif
> myFunction();
```

This would prevent them from appearing in the documentation, but they would still be available to the implementation.